# Why does "rails generate migration" call "invoke activerecord"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, invoke

When running:

```
 rails generate migration <someaction> field:type
```

I can see it is performing two actions:

1. Call invoke active_record
2. Create a migration file.

I understand perfectly why it is generating the migration file, but why does it invoke ActiveRecord? This bothers me because what if I want to create the migration file manually? how would I mimic this invocation (if it's even necessary..)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MigrationGenerator` generator:

1) Loads your ORM (which by default in Rails is Active Record) to have it extend the correct 'ORM'::Migration class (again by default this is ActiveRecord::Migration)

2) It is itself an extension of the `NamedBase` generator which sees if your running Active Record to decide if it should pluralize the table names.  This is so if you run

```
rails generate migration AddPartNumberToProducts part_number:string
```

or

```
rails generate migration AddPartNumberToProduct part_number:string
```

You get the same results in your file.

So the short answer is, you do not need to invoke active_record to create a migration by hand, but if you do and you are using Active Record make sure that your table names are pluralized in your migration file.

Answer (score 0):

[activerecord gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord) is invoked to generate the migration file.

If you look closely, the super class of a migration file is an [ActiveRecord::Migration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) class.